# How to make column name dynamic with spool on ORACLE?

Tags: oracle, plsql, spool

I want to ask, is it possible to use cursor to looping the string value? For example I have 3 title column for my '.txt' report :

```
COLUMN "DATE" format a15
COLUMN "SUBJECT" format a8
COLUMN "CLASS" format a10
```

and the result is like:

```
DATE                       SUBJECT                CLASS
----------------------     ------------------     -----------------
08-Apr-2016                 Science                10  
08-Apr-2016                 Social                 11
```

Now, the column name is still generic or hardcode. Then, I want to return the string value to replace the "DATE", "SUBJECT" and "CLASS" to be dynamic. So just follow to the data that loaded to database.

For example :
I have table that is filled up with these data:

```
TITLE_COLUMN1               TITLE_COLUMN2                 TITLE_COLUMN3
DATE                        SUBJECT                       CLASS
```

I want to select the value from TITLE_COLUMN1, TITLE_COLUMN2, TITLE_COLUMN3 to be on my column name. So what is the better way? Using

> Cursor

or using

> Variable

?

Thanks for the advise and help.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  If you don't care about the COLUMN settings, you could write a PL/SQL block that builds a dynamic query, opens a cursor, and then use the `print` command to print the cursor results.  But you won't be able to use the COLUMN formatting commands.  If your objective is just to generate an output file, I would tend to use `utl_file` maybe based on Tom Kyte's SQL*Unloader rather than trying to jump through all the hoops needed in SQL*Plus if you want to do a bunch of formatting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQLPlus and you are speaking about [substitution variables](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/entry/sqlplus_101_substitution_varia), you can make this:

```
column title_column1 new_value vc1
column title_column2 new_value vc2
column title_column3 new_value vc3
select title_column1,title_column2,title_column3 from test_columns;
select &vc1,&vc2,&vc3 from test_data;
```